# Python cannot see module after installing via pip

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I'm still trying to master the science of installing packages via pip. When I run pip to install geocoder, I get the following:

```
(base) C:\Users\MBSanders>python -m pip install geocoder
Requirement already satisfied: geocoder in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.38.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from geocoder) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from geocoder) (0.17.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from geocoder) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from geocoder) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ratelim in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from geocoder) (0.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->geocoder) (2019.3.9)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->geocoder) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->geocoder) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->geocoder) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ratelim->geocoder) (4.4.0)
```

When I run

```
os.getcwd()
```

in spyder/python, I get

```
'C:\\Users\\MBSanders'
```

My question is, why do I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geocoder'
```

When I run

```
import geocoder
```

I'm somewhat new to python. Please let me know if additional info is needed to trouble shoot. I'm within a federal agency so I do not have admin rights.

When I run sys.path in the console, I get

```
sys.path
Out[12]: 
['F:\\Users\\MBSanders',
 'C:\\Users\\MBSanders\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\MBSanders\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\MBSanders\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\MBSanders\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3',
 '',
 'C:\\Users\\MBSanders\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\MBSanders\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\MBSanders\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\MBSanders\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\MBSanders\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\MBSanders\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'F:\\Users\\MBSanders\\.ipython']
```

Comment: is it on the list of installed packages when you run `pip list`

Comment: When I typed "pydoc modules" into the Anaconda Prompt, geocoder was in the list.

Comment: Run `sys.path` to see where python looks for. There should be `c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages` in there but since `geocoder` doesn't get imported it probably isn't. If that's the case it should be resolved by adding the path to the `PYTHONPATH` evnironment variable which would require administrator privileges. If that's not an option you can always include it manually by doing something like this `sys.path.insert(1, r"c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages")` but it could mess up your other imports.

Comment: It sure looks like you have two versions of anaconda installed, one in C:\Msanders, one in C:\programdata. geocoder is already installed in the C:\programdata one, but you are using the one in C:\MSanders

Comment: Messing with PYTHONPATH might fix the immediate problem but it will get you into an even bigger mess down the road. You want to make sure you have the same anaconda environment activated when you're installing and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're running python on the terminal, and `python` is the command you're using to run it, try doing `python -m pip install geocoder`. That'll install it for the python build you want to use. Or if you know the full path to the python build you're using, you can do something similar like `/path/to/python -m pip install geocoder`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python 3.7 or 3.8 you may need to pip3.7 `or` pip3.8 install  if you OS is recognizing a 2.x version as default